# How to find out what intent callback reference to what

Tags: android, list, android-intent, camera, adapter

this may sounds stupid but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a custom ListAdapter that populates the rows with images, text and other stuff thats all structured by my models. Now I want that when you click on a (any) image in that list, the camera shall open and the user should be able to take a picture and then the image that was clicked should display the pic that was taken with the cam. Get it?

Now in the adapter I just do something like that:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...stuff...
    ImageView image = (ImageView) elementView.findViewById(R.id.element_image);
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
        }
    ...other stuff...
});
```

I add for each ImageView a onClick Option that can open the camera and let the user take a picture.
The problem is that the context (my MainActivity) gets a callback on the method 'onActivityResult', but how do I know which callback belongs to which ImageView?

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent)
```

Is it possible to send a reference within the intent? **Or how should it know which intent-call belongs to which ImageView?**

I hope you understand my question. Otherwise just ask. Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and easy solution, would be to store the `position` of your `ListAdapter` in the `SharedPreference`. In you `onActivityResult`, you can extract that `SharedPreference` again, to know which one was requested:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // Store in shared preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
    prefEditor.putInt("position_in_adapter",position);
    prefEditor.commit();

    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
}
```

And than in your activity result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent){

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("FileName",MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Extract again
    int position= sharedPref.getInt("position_in_adapter", -1);
}
```

EDIT: Another option is to use your requestCode as your position. E.g.

```
startActivityForResult(takePicture, position);
```

and extract it again in your onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent){
    // requestCode is the position in your adapter
}
```

Comment: nice idea, but is there not a simple solution? thats more like a hack.

Comment: you can also use the requestCode to pass your position back and forth. See the edit. I don't think you can add it as a paramter in your intent, since you don't have control over the intent returned by the camera application

Comment: @StupidBird not a hack, that is how android works :) Pass intents, parcelables, bundles around between activities.

Comment: @t0mm13b well you have to agree that it's not really clean code ;) Is there a reason why we don't have a 'nicer' solution? Like passing references in intents or redirecting callbacks (lol) or a wrapper or just something simpler? I just can't believe that there ain't a better solution. But aslong I've found something else I'll stick with this one..

Comment: As for *redirecting callbacks (lol)* not entirely sure what you mean. ;) The gist of Android is based on `Intent`s to pass data around between activities. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) :)